# Design changed for tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, design

Is `border-radius` added for the tags in Stack Overflow/Meta Stack Overflow?

Previously the tags are in the sharp rectangles, now the edges are looking differently.

Is there any new change in the design?

[image: Tag edges]

Comment: Also on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283314/network-wide-change-to-question-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283326/312043), it was an experimental style change that caused the design issue. No where it is not reproducible.

The actual content form the above answered link is follows:

> This was an oversight. We're exploring some potential updates to the tag editor and the experimental styling ended up bleeding into the rest of the site by accident.
>
> Fix is rolling out now.